# PHP Merge const arrays to new const array without nesting

Tags: php, arrays, merge, constants

Let's say I have 3 `const` arrays:

```
const A = ["a", "aa", "aaa"];
const B = ["b", "bb"];
const C = ["c"];
```

I now want to merge / combine those into another `const D` array without nesting them. How can I do this?

Basically I'm looking for something like `array_merge()`, but for constants, because as we all know, expressions can't be assigned to constants.

**The result I'm looking for is**

```
const D = ["a", "aa", "aaa", "b", "bb", "c"];
```

which is what

```
const D = array_merge(A, B, C);
```

would provide me with, *if* expressions were allowed for constants.

I've tried

```
const D = A + B + C;
```

but that leaves me with just the contents of `A` in `D`.

I've also tried

```
const D = [A, B, C];
```

but, as to expect, this results in an array of arrays `[["a", "aa", "aaa"], ["b", "bb"], ["c"]]` which *isn't* what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator for arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.unpack-inside-array) (also known as unpacking) since PHP 7.4 ([initial RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array)):

```
const D = [...A, ...B, ...C];
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/HOpYH**

I don't think there is any (other) way to do this with previous versions.

Comment: Genius. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work with string keys before 8.1